# How to get response on python client from a nodeJS server

Tags: node.js, sockets, python-2.7, socket.io

I'm trying to build a simple chat app using a NodeJS server with socket.IO and a client written in python 2.7 using socketIO-client package.
The js server is on local and is very simple :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on("chat_message", function(msg){
        io.emit("chat_message", msg);               
    });
});
```

This chat app works for several pages opened in my browser.
(source comes from : http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ )

I wanted to connect this server from a python client, and I succesfully emit from python to js server (text entered in python client appears into the browser).

The problem is the following :
When I type some text into the browser, Python doesn't print it into the shell.

Here is the code I use on python side :

```
def communicate(self, msg):
    logging.debug('processing event : %s', msg)     
    self.socketIO.emit("chat_message", msg, self.on_chat_message)

def on_chat_message(self, *args):
    output = ''
    index = 0
    for a in args:
        output += ' | '+str(index)+' : '+str(a)
        index += 1

    logging.debug('processing server output : ' + output)   
    return
```

As the server emits to all connected clients, python should normally handle it into the callback 'on_chat_message' but, it doesn't work.

I also tried to add a self.socketIO.wait_for_callbacks() to the python, without success.

If someone has an idea about what I'm doing it wrong, it would be great =D !
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get a response from the server on my python client.

My mistake was to not 'wait' on the socketIO variable, so I didn't catch any feedback.

To properly handle server responses, I use a BaseNamespace class which is binded to the socket, and handle basic events : overriding of the function on_event

```
def on_event(self, event, *args):
    #Catch your event and do stuff
```

If an event is handled by the class, a flag is raised up and checked by the client.

```
def communicate(self, msg):     
    self.socketIO.emit('chat_message', msg)

def wait_for_server_output(self):
    while(1):
        self.socketIO.wait(seconds=1)
        ns = self.socketIO.get_namespace()
        if ns.flag.isSet():
            data = ns.data_queue.get()
            ns.flag.clear()
```

These two functions are managed by 2 threads inside the client code.

Hoping this will help =)